# Vuex, firebase . Cannot retrieve the user data. Phone is undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, vuex

I am creating the user profile edit page.

Now, I want to retrieve user name, phone number and email address from my firebase real time database.

I could retrieve and show username and email address in the input fields. I cannot see only phone number.

I checked vuex dev console, and I found phone is undefined in the vuex.

[image]
[image]
In the database, I could correctly insert all the data.
[image]

I could understand the reason, but I cannot fix this issue.

This is my store/index.js.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import fireApp from '@/plugins/firebase'
import admin from './admin'

Vue.use(Vuex)


export default new Vuex.Store({
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    user: null,
    error: null,
    busy: false,
    jobDone: false
  },
  mutations: {
    // setCounter(state, payload) {
    //     state.counter = state.counter + payload
    // }
    setUser (state, payload) {
      state.user = payload
    },
    setError (state, payload) {
      state.error = payload
    },
    clearError (state, payload) {
        state.error = null
    },
    setBusy (state, payload) {
        state.busy = payload
    },
    setJobDone (state, payload) {
        state.jobDone = payload
    },
  },
  actions: {
    signUpUser({commit}, payload) {
      commit('setBusy', true)
      commit('clearError')
      //1.Signup new user.
      //2.Update firebase user profile & set local user data.
      //3.Add user data into database
      //4.Attach user to consumer group
      let newUser = null
      
      fireApp.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(payload.email, payload.password)
          .then(userCredential => {
            newUser = userCredential.user;
            var user = fireApp.auth().currentUser;
            
            return  user.updateProfile({
                displayName: payload.fullname,
                
              })
              .then(() => {
                
                const currentUser = {
                  id: user.uid,
                  name: payload.fullname,
                  phone: payload.phone,
                  //phone: user.phone,
                  email: payload.email,
                  role: 'consumer'
              }
              commit('setUser', currentUser)
              commit('setBusy', false)
              })
          })
          .then(() => {
            return fireApp.database().ref('users/' + newUser.uid).set({
                name: payload.fullname,
                phone: payload.phone,
                email: payload.email,
                createdAt: new Date().toISOString()
            })
          })
          .then(() => {
            return fireApp.database().ref('groups').orderByChild('name').equalTo('Customer').once('value')
                  .then(snapshot => {
                      const groupKey = Object.keys(snapshot.val())[0]
                      let groupedUser = {}
                      groupedUser[newUser.uid] = payload.fullname
                      return fireApp.database().ref(`userGroups/${groupKey}`).update(groupedUser)
                  })
          })
          .then(() => {
              commit('setJobDone', true)
              commit('setBusy', false)
          })
          .catch(error => {
              commit('setBusy', false)
              commit('setError', error)
          })
      },

    loginUser({commit}, payload) {
      commit('setBusy', true)
        commit('clearError')
        console.log('Login')
        commit('setJobDone', true)
        commit('setBusy', false)
    },

    loginUser({commit}, payload) {
      commit('setBusy', true)
      commit('clearError')
      //1.login user
      //2.Find group user logins
      //3.set logged in user
      fireApp.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(payload.email, payload.password)
      .then(user => {
          const authUser = {
              id: user.uid,
              name: user.displayName,
              phone: user.phone,
              email: user.email
          }
          return fireApp.database().ref('groups').orderByChild('name').equalTo('Administrator').once('value')
          .then(snapshot => {
              const groupKey = Object.keys(snapshot.val())[0]
              return fireApp.database().ref(`userGroups/${groupKey}`).child(`${authUser.id}`).once('value')
              .then(ugroupSnap => {
                  if(ugroupSnap.exists()) {
                      authUser.role = 'admin'
                  } else {
                      authUser.role = 'customer'
                  }
                  commit('setUser', authUser)
                  commit('setBusy', false)
                  commit('setJobDone', true )
              })
          })
      })
      .catch(error => {
          commit('setBusy', false)
          commit('setError', error)
      })
  },
  logOut({commit}) {
    fireApp.auth().signOut()
    commit('setUser', null)
  },

  setAuthStatus({commit}) {
    fireApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if(user) {
            const authUser = {
                id: user.uid,
                name: user.displayName,
                phone: user.phone,
                email: user.email
            }
            fireApp.database().ref('groups').orderByChild('name').equalTo('Administrator').once('value')
            .then(snapshot => {
                const groupKey = Object.keys(snapshot.val())[0]
                fireApp.database().ref(`userGroups/${groupKey}`).child(`${authUser.id}`).once('value')
                .then(uGroupSnap => {
                    if(uGroupSnap.exists()) {
                        authUser.role = 'admin'
                    } else {
                        authUser.role = 'customer'
                    }
                    commit('setUser', authUser)
            })
        })
        }
    })
  },
  updateProfile ({commit, getters}, payload) {
      commit('setBusy', true)
      commit('clearError')
      commit('setBusy', false)
      commit('setJobDone', true)
  }
     
},
  getters: {
    user (state) {
      return state.user
    },
    loginStatus (state) {
      return state.user !== null && state.user !== undefined
    },
    userRole (state) {
      const isLoggedIn = state.user !== null && state.user !== undefined
      return(isLoggedIn) ? state.user.role : 'customer'
    },
    error (state) {
      return state.error
    },
    busy (state) {
        return state.busy
    },
    jobDone (state) {
        return state.jobDone
    }
  },
  modules: {
    admin: admin
  }
})
```

CustomerProfile.vue

```
<template>
<div>
    <img src="../img/svg/Mangosteen.png" alt="">
    <Navbar />
    <form @submit.prevent="updateProfile">
    <b-card
    class="profile-card"
    >
    <div>
        <b-form>
            <p class="mt-3 text-center profile-title">Profile</p>
            <b-form-input
            id="input-1"
            v-model="fullname"
            type="text"
            required
            placeholder="fullname"
            class="mt-5 input"
            name="fullname" 
            v-validate="'required'" 
            :class="{ 'mt-5 input': errors.has('fullname') }">
            >
            </b-form-input>
            <p v-show="errors.has('fullname')" class="validate text-center">{{ errors.first('fullname') }}</p> 
            <b-form-input
            id="input-2"
            v-model.number="phone"
            type="tel"
            required
            placeholder="phone number"
            class="mt-5 input"
            name="phone number" 
            v-validate="'required'" 
            :class="{ 'mt-5 input': errors.has('phone number') }">
            >
            </b-form-input>
            <p v-show="errors.has('phone number')" class="validate text-center">{{ errors.first('phone number') }}</p>  
            <b-form-input
            id="input-3"
            v-model="email"
            type="email"
            required
            placeholder="Email"
            class="mt-5 input"
            name="email" 
            v-validate="'required|email'" 
            :class="{ 'mt-5 input': errors.has('email') }">
            >
            </b-form-input>
            <p v-show="errors.has('email')" class="validate text-center">{{ errors.first('email') }}</p>
            <error-bar :error="error"></error-bar> 
            </b-form>
        <b-button class="update-btn" type="submit">Update</b-button>
        </div>
    </b-card>
    </form>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import Navbar from "@/components/Navbar.vue";
import ErrorBar from '@/components/ErrorBar'
import apiJobMixin from '@/mixins/apiJobMixin'
import fireApp from '@/plugins/firebase'
  
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        fullname: '',
        phone: null,
        email: '',
      }
    },
    mixins: [apiJobMixin],
    components: {
      ErrorBar: ErrorBar
    },
    // created () {
    //   this.$store.commit('clearError')
    // //   const user = this.$store.getters.user
    // //   if (user) {
    // //     this.fullname = user.fullname
    // //     this.phone = user.phone
    // //     this.email = user.email
    // //   }
    // var user = fireApp.auth().currentUser;
    //     var name, email, phone;

    //     if (user != null) {
    //     name = user.displayName;
    //     email = user.email;
    //     phone = user.phone;
    //     }
    // },
    mounted: function () {
      this.$store.commit('clearError')
      const user = this.$store.getters.user
      if (user) {
        this.fullname = user.name
        this.phone = user.phone
        this.email = user.email
        
      }
    },
    methods: {
      updateProfile () {
        this.$validator.validateAll()
          .then(result => {
            if (result) {
              this.$store.dispatch('updateProfile', { fullname: this.fullname, phone: this.phone, email: this.email })
            }
          })
      },
      jobsDone () {        
        this.$swal({
          title: 'Profile updated successfuly',
          icon: 'success'
        })
      }
    },
    // If data gone after page reload
    computed: {      
      userData () {
        return this.$store.getters.user
      }
    },
    watch: {      
      userData (value) {
        if (value) {
          this.fullname = value.name
          this.phone = value.phone
          this.email = value.email
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

> I want to know why phone object is not defined.

Comment: Can you confirm with a `console.log` before `commit('setUser', currentUser)` that `currentUser` contains the phone?

Comment: I put console.log('USER', currentUser) before commit('setUser', currentUser) in createUserWithEmailAndPassword function. And then, I could see all the data was inserted.

Comment: I put consol.log(user) at the end of mounted hook, then this time only phone was undefined. I could see others' value.